# Zutritt verboten vs Betreten verboten

Tags: meaning, translation, meaning-in-context, difference

Zu meiner großen Überraschung bin ich gerade in einer Betriebsanleitung auf diese zwei Ausdrücke gestoßen:

> 1. *Zutritt verboten* und
> 2. *Betreten verboten*.

Der Autor der Betriebsanleitung meinte offensichtlich, dass es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den beiden gibt. So ergibt sich auch aus dem weiteren Inhalt selbst, dass der erste Bereich "nicht betreten werden kann" und was den zweiten betrifft, da können "beim Auftreten Einrichtungen beschädigt werden".

Aus meinen Suchergebnissen habe ich jedoch nicht viel erfahren. Das Piktogramm ist für beide Warnungen gleich. Wie kann man den Bedeutungsunterschied erklären und die Ausdrücke so ins Englische übersetzen, dass den Unterschied eingehalten wird?

Comment: Du solltest uns nach Möglichkeit noch ein paar weitere Zitate, möglichst wörtlich, geben. So ergibt es für mich wenig Sinn, einen Zutritt zu einem Bereich zu verbieten, der "nicht betreten werden kann".

Answer (score 12):

Die Erwähnung des Auftretens ist ein guter Hinweis auf das, worauf der Autor hinaus will.

Beim **Betreten** geht es hauptsächlich darum, den Boden nicht zu betreten (und ihn oder Dinge darauf damit eventuell zu beschädigen). Dazu muss der Bereich nicht zwangsläufig von sich aus unzugänglich sein. So würde man in einem Park typischerweise Schilder mit der Aufschrift

> Betreten verboten!

vor/auf einer offenen Rasenfläche finden, nicht aber mit

> Zutritt verboten!

denn **Zutritt** kann man nur in Bereiche bekommen, die in irgendeiner Art und Weise von ihrer Umgebung abgesperrt sind (bis auf einen Eingang, an dem man dann diesen Zutritt gewährt bekommen kann, oder auch nicht). Die Situation mit dem Rasen ändert sich daher, wenn die gesamte Fläche meterhoch umzäunt ist - dann würde man eher den Hinweis

> Zutritt verboten!

erwarten, nicht

> Betreten verboten!

Die Grenze ist natürlich schwammig, und es gibt viele Situationen, in denen beide Ausdrücke passen. Grundsätzlich gilt aber: Betreten verboten -> Fokus auf dem Betreten der *Fläche* / Zutritt verboten: Fokus auf Durchschreiten der *Umrandung*.

Ich bin kein englischer Muttersprachler, also kann es sein, dass ich die Nuancen da nicht ganz richtig wiedergebe, aber ich glaube, die Entsprechung wäre in etwa *No trespassing* vs. *No entrance*.

Comment: Ich sehe den von dir behaupteten Unterschied *nicht*.

Comment: Den in der englischen Übersetzung oder in der deutschen Erklärung? Letztere ist nämlich im Prinzip die gleiche wie bei den andern beiden Antworten auch..

Comment: +1 für die englische Übersetzung

Comment: "Gelände oder ein Grundstück" <-> "Fläche" , "Durchgängen oder Türen" <-> "Durchschreiten der Umrandung"

Comment: Beide Begriffe beinhalten *treten* - Deswegen *Betreten* als "seine Füße auf den Boden stellen" einzuordnen und "Zutritt" nicht und daraus einen Bedeutungsunterschied herzuleiten, ergibt für mich keinen Sinn.

Comment: @tofro Ich hab den expliziten Hinweis auf den Boden ja auch vom *auftreten* abgeleitet, nicht vom *betreten*.

Comment: Und das macht genau welchen Unterschied? "zutreten" macht normalerweise noch mehr kaputt als "auftreten" und "betreten". Mir erscheint schon diese Originalerklärung in der Frage etwas schwurblig.

Comment: Davon abgesehen ergibt der Blick auf die Präfixe aber sogar durchaus Sinn, wenn ich genauer drüber nachdenke. "Zu-" vermittelt wesentlich mehr das Bild einer gezielten Bewegung *zu* etwas. "Be-" dagegen ist eher "man führt eine Handlung an etwas aus" (egal aus welcher Richtung).

Comment: "Zutreten" als Verb hat sehr offensichtlich eine andere Meinung als "Zutritt" ...

Comment: Tut mir leid - dem kann ich nicht zustimmen. Aber nachdem ich gesehen habe, dass der Unsinn möglicherweise schon aus dem Originaltext stammt, oder aber wir einfach nicht genug Originaltext haben, habe ich mein Downvote zurückgezogen.

Comment: Ja, wie es aussieht haben wir da einfach ein anderes Sprachgefühl (kann ja auch regional begründet sein, wer weiß). Ich bin dir nicht böse ;) (hatte mich halt nur gewundert, warum du bei den anderen Antworten, die ins gleiche Horn stoßen, nichts auszusetzen hattest)

Answer (score 7):

*Zutritt* bezeichnet normalerweise das das Eintreten in einen Raum oder ein Gelände. Verbietet man, dass Leute in ein Gebäude oder auf ein Grundstück kommen dürfen, verweigert man den Zutritt.

Mit *Betreten* kann sowohl das Eintreten in einen Raum oder ein Gelände gemeint sein, aber auch das *auf etwas treten*. Somit könnte das Betreten einer Planke dazu führen, dass sie bricht.

**EDIT**
Noch ein weiterer Faktor könnte sein, dass *Zutritt verboten* eventuell auch beinhaltet, dass es in irgendeiner Form ein Hindernis zu überwinden gilt (z.B. eine Tür, einen Zaun, etc.) und man sich erst Zutritt *verschaffen* muss, während *Betreten verboten* eventuell auch Bereiche betrifft, die ansonsten nicht sonderlich gesichert sind (z.B. Grünflächen, Sportplätze, Beete, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Betreten verboten bezieht sich meistens auf eine Gelände oder ein Grundstück. Als Beispiel kann hier eine Baustelle, ein Firmengelände oder ein Fußballrasen sein.
Hierbei geht es nicht um eine Gefahrenabwehr sondern eher um Besitzansprüche.
siehe: [Betreten verboten Bedeutung](http://www.etikettenwissen.de/wiki/Betreten_verboten)

Die Baustelle wäre hier wahrscheinlich eine Außnahme, hier spielt die Gefahrenabwehr auch eine gewisse Rolle (Maschinen, Treppen, usw.)

Zutritt verboten verwendet man vor allem im Zusammenhang mit Durchgängen oder Türen. Solche Schilder findest du vor allem bei geschützten oder gefährlichen Bereichen. Dies können Serverräume von Firmen sein in die nur bestimmtes Personal Zutritt hat (geschützt) und können auch Räume oder Käfige sein in denen automatisierte Roboter arbeiten (gefährlich).

Sehr oft wird 'Zutritt für Unbefugte verboten' genannt, das bedeutet das nur autorisiertes Personal diesen Raum betreten darf, da bevor Betreten des Raums eventuell Sicherheitsvorkehrungen getroffen werden müssen (Maschine ausschalten oder eventuell nur einen bestimmten Bereich des Raumes betreten).

Answer (score 0):

Auf einem Warnschild, das einen Raum oder Bereich vor dem Zugang schützen soll, bedeuten die zwei Worte *exakt dasselbe*: "Bleib draußen!". Den Bedeutungsunterschied, so wie du ihn in deinem Text beschreibst, halte ich für weit hergeholt, solange er nicht (wesentlich) genauer erklärt wird.

*Zutritt* hat im Deutschen allerdings noch eine Nebenbedeutung, nämlich *das Recht und die Mittel zum Betreten* - Als Synonym für "Zugang". So kann man zum Beispiel fragen:

> Wer hat denn Zutritt zum Serverraum?

und meint damit "wer kann (vielleicht, weil er den Schlüssel hat) und darf (z.B. weil er der Systemadministrator ist) da rein?".

> <s>Wer hat denn Betreten zum Serverraum?</s>

würde keinen Sinn ergeben.

"Zutritt verboten" würde in diesem Sinne meinen: "Auch wenn du meinst, du darfst und kannst, bleib' trotzdem draußen" (z.B., weil es im Augenblick gefährlich ist und der Raum mit CO2 geflutet ist). Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass dein Text diesen Unterschied meint.

Es könnte also sein, dass dein Text einen Unterschied macht zwischen  Betreten durch "normale" Personen und solche mit besonderen Befugnissen (z.B. einem Wartungstechniker) - Auch wenn die meisten Muttersprachler diesen Unterschied nicht auf Anhieb an den beiden Begriffen festmachen würden.

Sollte das der Fall sein - das kannst nur du selbst anhand deines Texts beurteilen - würde ich "Betreten" mit *entrance* und "Zutritt" mit *access* oder *admittance* übersetzen oder die "Steigerung der Zugangsbeschränkung" über ein Adverb (***absolutely*** no entrance) ausdrücken.

Comment: Man darf in diesem Zusammenhang noch hinweisen auf die verbreitete Formulierung "Zutritt für Unbefugte verboten". Ja, für wen denn sonst? "Zutritt für Befugte verboten" würde sich ja selbst widersprechen. Aber "Unbefugten" ist der Zutritt ja sowieso schon per definitionem verboten, denn sie sind ja unbefugt [zuzutreten].

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das stimmt so nicht ganz - Man kann auch den Zutritt für Befugte (zumindestens temporär) verbieten (siehe Antwort). Das ist so ähnlich wie die Aufschrift "This door must be kept closed at all times", die man oft in englischsprachlichen Ländern findet und sich fragt, warum man dann überhaupt eine Tür hingebaut hat...

Comment: @tofro Wenn man den (normalerweise) Befugten den Zutritt temporär verbietet, sind sie für diesen Zeitraum allerdings auch Unbefugte.

Comment: Aber generell hast du Recht, die Formulierung ergibt durchaus Sinn, wenn man als Gegenpart zu "Zutritt für Unbefugte verboten" nicht "Zutritt für *Befugte* verboten"  sieht, sondern "Zutritt für *alle* verboten".

Comment: Man kann durchaus betreten im Zusammenhang mit dem Serverraum verwenden: Wer darf denn den Serverraum betreten?

Comment: @Uwe dann hast du das "dürfen" ins Verb gepackt. Bei "Zutritt" ist es schon im Begriff.